# How can I shift all the letters in the grid to the left?

Tags: python, loops, grid

So I wrote a code that yields a grid with the help of some helpful stackoverflow users, and here it is..

```
import random
import string

for x in range(4):
    for y in range(4):
        print( '['+random.choice(string.ascii_letters)+']',end='' )
    print()
```

and now I want to create a function `moveleft(grid)` that will move every column to the left

For instance, if my grid looks like this at first..

```
[k][b][s][v]
[u][w][p][O]
[t][i][i][K]
[n][J][r][f]
```

then after executing `moveleft(grid)`, this will be my grid,

```
[v][k][b][s]
[O][u][w][p]
[K][t][i][i]
[f][n][J][r]
```

what should I write up for `moveleft(grid)` to work as the example provided above?

Comment: Your code does not _store_ the grid, it just _prints_ it. So the first step is to store the grid, perhaps in a `list` of `list`s, or a `numpy.ndarray` or whatever

Answer (score 2):

[numpy.roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) does this. For example,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> grid = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> grid
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> np.roll(grid, shift=1, axis=1)
array([[3, 1, 2],
       [6, 4, 5],
       [9, 7, 8]])
```